# website/application made with polymer components loads extremely slow on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

We are considering polymer technology (& the dart language) to develop a public/internet web application / web site.
When testing /validating the approach, we encountered a potential show-stopper.
The (basic) site is performing rather o.k. on different browsers & platforms, but it is extremely slow on Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1.

The problem does not seem to be related to our specific code, as it seems easy to reproduce the behaviour using, for example, the polymer demo (menu button):
https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-menu-button

On IE11 (11.0.9600.17351), it takes more than 16 seconds to load that page.
With the “UI Responsiveness” profiler of IE11, a .diagsession file was created: http://novonov.be/tmp/polymer-paper-menu-button-demo.diagsession
At first sight, the problem does not seem to be related to network traffic / number of files to be downloaded.
15.73 seconds are spent in “DOM event (readystatechanged)”.
We did not test another version of IE - only IE11.

Is there any solution/workaround available for this issue?
Or does this issue makes that a website / web-application created with polymer components will not work with a reasonable performance in IE(11)?
This could be a showstopper for public internet websites / web-applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to the problem was brought up by jakemac53 on https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/891

> Ah, so that one took me a bit to figure out but its because of the
>   shadow dom css polyfill running on the large css files being included
>   in each of your elements (specifically bootstrap). Luckily it is
>   pretty easy to disable this polyfill from running (and its not needed
>   for bootstrap). Simply add the "no-shim" attribute to all of your
>   linked stylesheets, so bootstrap for instance should look like:
>
> Otherwise the polyfill has to copy all the contents from the file and
>   apply its transformations, and then stamp the result into an inline
>   stylesheet. When this is done many times on a large stylesheet like
>   bootstrap it really slows things down.

Answer (score 3):

The [vulcanize tool](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/concatenating-web-components.html) is key to productionizing an app. Polyfill'd browsers like IE11 will be inherently slower than native HTML imports, so it's important to reduce the number of requests and setup work the polyfills have to do.

For example, I was able to take the SPA demo (https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/demos/spa/final.html) from ~20s to ~3.7s, just by running vulcanize: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/141105_7P_178Q/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the slowness on this example is caused by the sheer number of elements on the page. In the country selection dropdowns, there are ~240 paper-item elements, and there are 4 of those dropdowns, so total there are ~1000 paper-item elements on the page. Each of these has two custom elements, paper-ripple and core-icon, so now we are up to ~3000 custom elements, not to mention all the other elements. I confirmed that simply commenting out the majority of the countries dramatically improves performance.

In Firefox and IE they are running under the polyfills which magnifies their performance woes, and so that is why you are seeing such slowness in each of those browsers. Performance is definitely something that the Polymer team is actively working on (especially relating to the polyfills), but any time you have this many elements on the page it is going to cause issues in slower browsers.

Comment: One option here could be exploring using a core-list element inside the paper-menu-button element for these large dropdowns so that only the visible elements are actually on on the page. I messed around with that briefly and although I didn't get it to look the same visually yet it looks promising, the node count dropped from 80k to 8k and on IE11 it loads in around 5 seconds.

Comment: It looks like the core demo page has changed to not have such huge dropdown menus already, but you can see what my changes would have looked like here https://github.com/dart-lang/paper-elements/commit/62c77b. The demo now loads very quickly in chrome and is much faster in Firefox and IE11 than it was before (< 5 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

In response to @ebidel s answer.
I Dart this means to run `pub build` from command line instead from DartEditor.
When run from command line `mode=release` is used by default. DartEditor calls `pub build` with `mode=debug`. 
The release mode does tree-shaking and minification which leads to smaller code. As far as I know the other things `vulcanize` does for `Polymer.js` is done by the Dart Polymer transformer.

Some hints

admin_service_repository/admin_service_repository.dart

```dart
@observable List serviceDescriptions = toObservable([]);
// instead of
// @observable List serviceDescriptions = [];
```

so Polymer gets notified about changes even when loading the data returns after 
Polymer already created the view from the `serviceDescriptions` list.

```dart
for (Map service in services) {
  //String name = service['name'];
  //ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription(name, service['defaultUrl'], service['description'], service['exampleContent']);
  //addService(sd);
  serviceDescriptions.addAll(
      services.map((s) => new ServiceDescription(s['name'], s['defaultUrl'], 
          s['description'], s['exampleContent']))); 
}
```

creating the list and adding the items to `services` could be simplified a bit.

admin_service_repository/node_view.dart

```dart
  @observable get allChildren {
//    List list = [];
//    for (Node child in node.children.values) {
//      list.add(child);
//    }
//    return list;
    return node.children.values.toList(); 
  }
```

In `lib/invoke_service` you create a list of strings and concatenate them in the constructor.
You can create multi-line string literals like

```dart
String someString = r'''
 {
   xxxx
 }
''';
```

I added

```dart
- polymer:
    inline_stylesheets:
      lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css: false
      lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css: false
      lib/css/op.css: false
      lib/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css: false
```

to the `pubspec.yaml` to get rid of the warnings after upgrading to Polymer 0.15.xxx.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
I am not sure that that the vulcanize approach will significantly improve the performance.  As indicated: “the problem does not seem to be related to network traffic / number of files to be downloaded”.   Also, I understand that its functionality is covered by the Dart Polymer transformer.

Our Dart code was already built (to js) using the “pub build --mode=release” argument (outside the DartEditor).  Removing the argument gives the same result.

I am afraid this means that the Polymer technology is currently not really ready to be used for IE(11) / public web sites…

Comment: I'm not sure if `checked mode` applies to built JS as well as to Dart code but if so building in release mode should also improve execution speed but if you already built in release mode then there is nothing more to gain I guess. Maybe someone from the Polymer.dart team has other ideas. How do the core-/paper-elements demo pages perform on IE? (I don't have IE available here to check myself). Can you make the code of your project available?

Comment: I put Zip file with the code on: http://novonov.be/tmp/op-code.zip
In web folder: index. html & admin.html are the starting points.
BTW. Today, after upgrade my laptop to to Yosemite - Safari 8, one specific part of the site (under admin.html) does not seem to work properly anymore in Safari 8… (still ok in Chrome, Firefox & slow on IE11) -> I will look into that later.

Comment: Have you tried to use a newer Polymer version? Your `pubspec.yaml` limits Polymer to `<0.13.0` current is `0.15.xxx`.

Comment: Have you tried without jQuery? I have no experience using jQuery with Polymer.dart maybe there is some conflict?

Comment: If you update Polymer you will run into https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/reference/error-messages/#polymer_42

Comment: Thanks! Using the latest & greatest Polymer version makes it run fine with Yosemite Safari 8.
I will try later on without jquery, but then I might have to get rid of some bootstrap-framework parts too.
The performance problems for IE11 still persists.
As it also occurs for polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-menu-button, I might try to log it as a bug for the polymer project.

Comment: Removing jQuery is only temporary to corner possible culprits. That the official demo page also has this performance problems makes it less probable that any measures will bring the desired performance improvement :-/. Creating an issue is a good idea.

Comment: I looked at the code you provided and I found a few things you might be interested in (see my updated answer). Beside that all looks fine.